# Parse Query using Geoquery

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm running queries on some objects with linked geoquery data.

However, none of the queries work and return the following error

**location object expected, location array not in correct format**

Console logs show that

gp is definitely an object, is definitely a Parse Geopoint and has correct coordinates.

I'm stumped, any advice appreciated

```
let gp = null;
if (search.hasOwnProperty("geo")) {
console.log(`Geodata ${JSON.stringify(search.geo)}`);
gp = new Parse.GeoPoint({
  latitude: search.geo.lat,
  longitude: search.geo.long
});

console.log(`GP type ${typeof gp}, GP ${JSON.stringify(gp)}`);

let query = new Parse.Query("Place");
query.near("location", gp);
query.find({
  success: (e) => console.log(`Geo near query ${JSON.stringify(e)}`),
  error: (e) => console.log(`Geo near error ${JSON.stringify(e)}`)
});
};
```

Comment: is "location" storing values as Geopoints in parse DB? i would try something similar with `query.withinMiles("location", gp, 1.0);`

Comment: Yep, they're saved as Geopoints and I've checked type in dashboard. I've tried other similar GP queries, same results.

Answer (score 0):

I created something on my side that work with the following code:

```
 let gp = new Parse.GeoPoint({
     latitude: 37.337845,
     longitude: -122.037687
  });

  // 1. first run this in order to save some location to your DB
  var LocationTest = Parse.Object.extend("LocationTest");
  var locationObject = new LocationTest();
  locationObject.set("location",gp);
  locationObject.set("name","location name test");

  locationObject.save().then(function(result){

  },function(error){

  });

  // 2. Uncomment and run this query after you save the object above
  /* 
  var query = new Parse.Query("LocationTest");
  query.near("location",gp);
  query.find().then(function(results){

  },function(error){

  }); */
```

Please first run the first piece of code in order to save a location to your DB and then run the second part for query what you have saved.

The reason that you are getting this error can be because your location is not saved as an object but as an array on your database or maybe because your location field is not of type **PFGeoPoint**
what i suggest you is maybe to first run my code above and check if it works and then maybe try to change maybe the class name or the field name in your DB and save and query from a different field.

This code works for me on parse-server 2.2.17 (the latest version) so please also check that your parse-server is up to date by running **npm install** on your app

Comment: Think I've worked out what issue is. Geoqueries appear to break when the geopoint is empty / has no data. Had a few objects with no associated geopoints, deleted those and it appears to work. Going to test more

Answer (score 0):

With some experimentation, found that geoqueries fail if any of the objects being queried don't have geodata associated with it.

Bit more severe than just not having geodata, even if it has a geodata property, and that property is **empty**, it will crash.

Solution is to check that latitude and longitude exist before querying that object